# Insufficient Access Rights: The entry cn=schema cannot be modified due to insufficient access rights

Tags: opendj

I tried to assign an admin user to do the update schema.

Here is the global-aci in

```
'cn=Access Control Handler,cn=config'
ds-cfg-global-aci: (target="ldap:///cn=schema")(targetattr="*")(version 3.0; acl "admin user can update schema"; allow (all,import,export) userdn="ldap:///uid=admin,ou=People,ou=Subjects,dc=example,dc=com";)
```

And the admin user has assigned:
ds-privilege-name: subentry-write
ds-privilege-name: update-schema

If I give this user one more privilege,

```
ds-privilege-name: bypass-acl
```

then this 'admin' user can add modify `cn=schema`, add attributes.

but If I remove `'ds-privilege-name: bypass-acl'`, then the exception thrown again.

So it is clear that my `global-aci` doesn't work?
Do I need any other aci settings for the `cn=schema`, to enable the user to update schema?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes under `cn=schema` are operational attributes.
I would suggest to change the `(targetattr="*")` into `(targetattr="*||+")`